# Git Merge Specifics Commits

Tags: git, git-merge

Suppose I have several tasks and every one is developed in a branch. I have three branchs too: **develop**, **qa**, **production**. Usually I merge every ticket into **develop** when is **ready**.

How can I merge into **qa** and **production** only the tasks I need from the branch **develop**?

**Example:**

I have **task1**, **task2**, **task3**, I merge to develop the task1, then the task2, then the task3. I delete the 3 tasks branchs. Now I need to merge the commits of **task1** into **qa**. How can I do that?

Comment: Once you've merged in task2 and task3, you can't very accurately. If you merge in task1, and no additional commits were merged in for task1, just `git merge commit_sha_for_task1` into the QA branch. Otherwise you're left with cherry picking individual commits. Basically, unless you are ready for a task to be in QA, don't merge it into dev. You might just want to deploy the task1 branch to QA for preliminary testing.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, I would not delete the task branches if you wish to merge them into QA as well (though I would recommend a different workflow altogether, like [Git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)). If you have indeed already deleted the task branches, you can restore them with the following: `git branch task1 ABC^2`, where `ABC` is the commit where you merged `task1` into `develop`. Then simply merge `task1` into QA.

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to merge the commits from a particular branch, merging them from that specific branch is the cleanest approach to do so.  If you've deleted the branch from the remote (but not local), then restore the remote and merge (for records' sake).  If you've deleted from both remote and local, then look through your terminal history to see if you still have the SHA, recreate the branch (through `git checkout <SHA> && git checkout -b <branch_name>`), and continue from there.

Otherwise, you're going to have to cherry-pick them across branches, and depending on if they were fast-forward commits or not, this would be a lot trickier.

The use of a `development` and `qa` branch is a bit dubious; I would presume that the testing would happen on either `development` or `qa`, but not both.

If the intention is to treat one of those branches as an integration branch (a point where all code for a release comes together), then use either `development` or `qa` alone.